# Lens mount adapter for Super Albinar lens to Sony alpha α6000 E-mount

Tags: lens, lens-adapter

I have the Sony alpha α6000 E-mount camera and have been gifted a Super Albinar Auto Zoom 80-200mm f/5.5 (macro) (with HOYA 49mm FL-day filter) and an Albinar auto twin converter 2x, both of which fit a Minolta XG-1.  Do I need to purchase a mount adapter from Minolta to Sony E-mount? It also came with many filters which I do not know how to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Minolta MC/MD to Sony E-mount adapter. Please note that most such adapters will not enable autofocus (if the older MC or MD lens even had AF) or electronic aperture control. You'll have to set the aperture via the ring on the lens and use manual exposure mode to set the shutter speed and ISO with the camera.